# Comportamento da função preg_match() para abreviação de nomes

Tags: php, regex

Montei uma função que recebe um nome completo com X nomes e sobrenomes e retorna apenas o primeiro nome e o último sobrenome. Caso tenha um conectivo(de, da, do, dos, etc) antes do último sobrenome, ele anexa no resultado.

Porém a função `preg_match()`, está retornando o contrário esperado pela minha `regex`.

Exemplo:

```
function abrevia($var) {
$nomes = explode(" ", $var);
$a = reset($nomes);
$c = end($nomes);
if (count($nomes) > 2) {
    $b = prev($nomes);
    if (preg_match('/^[^A-Z]*$/', $b{0})) {
        return implode(" ", array($a, $b, $c));
    }
}
return implode(" ", array($a, $c));
}

$a[1] = "João Testador dos Testes";
$a[2] = "João dos Testis Testando do Teste";
$a[3] = "João do Teste";

$b = array_map('abrevia', $a);

var_dump($b);
```

Retorna:

```
array (size=3)
1 => string 'João dos Testes' (length=16)
2 => string 'João do Teste' (length=14)
3 => string 'João do Teste' (length=14)
```

Dúvida:

Esta função abaixo, não deveria retornar `false`(0)?

```
$b = "da";
var_dump(preg_match('/^[^A-Z]*$/', $b{0})); //retorna 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$b = "da";
var_dump(preg_match('/^[^A-Z]*$/', $b{0}));
```

Sua regex diz, combine no inicio de linha(`^`) algo que não sejam letras maiusculas entre `A-Z`(`[^A-Z]`) seguido de qualquer caracter(`*`), quando  é passado `$b[0]` preg_match() aplica a regex apenas em `d` já vc está passando o indice da string, o retorno é 1 por que a combinação aconteceu.

Comment: Entendi, qual o operador de negação para letras maíusculas?
O que define que "não seja", ao invés do "seja" ?

O índice da string eu apliquei porque no caso, no meu AD, os nomes dos colaboradores sempre usam o conectivo com minúscula, mas não entendi porque ficou "não seja" ao invés de "seja" minúsculas? Fiquei um bom tempo quebrando a cabeça porque funcionou meu script, mas ao contrário. rs

Comment: O `^` dentro de uma lista`[]` nega o que estiver nela. Nesse [link](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/metacaracteres.html) tem a lista completa dos metacaracteres.

Comment: Agora ficou claro!

Answer (score 2):

A sua duvida foi respondida, mas você esta prevendo que os dados vão vir sempre formatados como você quer, ou seja nomes e sobrenomes com a primeira em maiúscula e o conectivo em minúsculo...

assim reduziria as possibilidades de erros:

```
<?php
    function abrevia($var) {
    $nomes = explode(" ", $var);
    $a = reset($nomes);
    $c = end($nomes);
    if (count($nomes) > 2) {
        $b = prev($nomes);
        if (preg_match('/^[deaos]{2,3}$/i', $b)) {
            return implode(" ", array($a, $b, $c));
        }
    }
    return implode(" ", array($a, $c));
    }

    $a[] = "João Testador dos Testes";
    $a[] = "joão dos testis testando teste";
    $a[] = "João do Teste";
    $a[] = "João Testador Das Dores";
    $a[] = "João Testador de Melo";
    $a[] = "João Testador Da Silva";

    $b = array_map('abrevia', $a);

    var_dump($b);
?>
```

retorna:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "João dos Testes"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "joão teste"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "João do Teste"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "João Das Dores"
  [4]=>
  string(12) "João de Melo"
  [5]=>
  string(13) "João Da Silva"
}
```

Comment: É porque vem de um Active Directory, aonde os dados são padronizados, não há essa possibilidade porque quebraria uma regra de cadastro.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso.

```
/**
 * Abreviar Nome
 * @param String $string Name user
 * @return string
 */
function FirstAndLastName($string) {
    $nome = explode(" ", $string);
    $first = $nome[0];
    $last = end($nome);
    if (count($nome) == 1) {
        $result = $nome[0];
    } else {
        $result = $first . ' ' . $last;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Não funciona, precisa mostrar os conectivos como João da Silva, sua função eliminaria o "da".
No caso, a minha função está correta, só tinha uma dúvida com relação ao retorno da `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 0):

faz assim

```
 $nome = 'JOAO DOS TESTES';
 $retira = array(' DE ', ' DOS ', ' E ', ' DO ', ' DA ', ' DAS ', ' DI ');
 $nomeLimpo = str_replace($retira, ' ', $nome);
```